# Create Dynamic ng-models for firebase use | ionic | firebase | angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, firebase, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularfire

I'm trying to make an app where users can tag other registered users in a post.

So the idea is if the user creates a new post. there is an ng-repeat for all the users available and for each of them a checkbox is created.

After the users are checked they have to be stored with the post in firebase. 
Now i cant seem to figure out how to dynamically add properties to my firebase push

```
  <div class="list">
      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">Titel</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Titel" ng-model="formData.title">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">Beschrijving</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Kaarten voor... etc" ng-model="formData.description">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">Prijs</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder=".-" ng-model="formData.price">
      </label>
    </div>
    <ion-list ng-repeat="user in users">
        <ion-checkbox ng-click="la()" ng-model="users[user.Username][user.id][user.voltooid == false]" >
    </ion-checkbox>
    </ion-list>
    <div class="button" ng-click="test()">test</div>
```

The push code

```
       $scope.formData = {};
       $scope.test = function (){
        console.log($scope.users);
        console.log($scope.formData);
        posts.push({ 
          title: $scope.formData.title, 
          description: $scope.formData.description,
          price: $scope.formData.price,
          users: {
            //dynamic data
          }
        });
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna give you an example how to retrieve and post dynamically your data.

Here is a factory to sync your data with a controller/ng-model, but you can include it in a controller.

```
.factory("Items", function($firebaseArray) {
    var itemsRef = new Firebase("https://YOUR-FIREBASE/");
    return $firebaseArray(itemsRef);
})
```

In your controller you retrieve your data in a scope

```
$scope.items = Items;
```

Then use the function of angularfire call $save that will update your data into your firebase.

```
$scope.la = function(){
$scope.items.$save($scope.users[user.name][check]);
}
```

Finally you can do something like that to retrieve and update your data

```
<ion-checkbox ng-click="la()" ng-model="users[user.name][check]">
```